# Webpack issue - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, react-redux

Following is my webpack config file,

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const publicPath = '/dist/build/';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const jsIncludes = [
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
];

module.exports = {
  //Content 
  entry: './index.js',
  // A SourceMap without column-mappings ignoring loaded Source Maps. 
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    //simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles. This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename which changes every compilation. You can either let the plugin generate an HTML file for you, supply your own template using lodash templates or use your own loader.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Inovmac'
    }),
    //Auto replacement of page when i save some file, even css
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
    //Be possible go back pressing the "back" button at chrome
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: false,
    stats: 'minimal',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
    //hotmodulereplacementeplugin
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
     { 
       test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], 
       include: /flexboxgrid/
       //Follow instructions at https://github.com/roylee0704/react-flexbox-grid
     },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: jsIncludes,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loaders: ["babel-loader"]
      }]
  },
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "services-inovmac",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build:dev": "webpack --env=dev --progress --profile --colors",
    "build:dist": "webpack --env=prod --progress --profile --colors"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "loadsh": "0.0.4",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.1.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

I am seeing following error when running the build `npm run build`

> services-inovmac@1.0.0 build /Users/venkatesheppili/Workspace/services-inovmac
>   webpack

Hash: 1f1ff22346a26e30edf8
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 252ms
Built at: 03/10/2020 7:21:23 PM
 2 assets
Entrypoint main = main.bundle.js main.map
[0] ./index.js 314 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

```
ERROR in ./index.js 7:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <Container />,
|   document.getElementById('root')
| );
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 2 hidden modules
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! services-inovmac@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the services-inovmac@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/venkatesheppili/.npm/_logs/2020-03-11T00_21_23_276Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What's the path of `index.js` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. I resolved it and left my answer. Hoping it helps someone else. I will try to monitor if anyone else has questions.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved my project by using following webpack configuration,

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const publicPath = '/dist/build/';
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
  entry: './index.jsx',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    })
  ],

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    host: 'localhost',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: false,
    stats: 'minimal',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, publicPath),
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        include: /flexboxgrid/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

This is my project structure,
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riRil.png)

Comment: Hi,I am having same problem with vue js